# Optimize an if statement with multiple elements in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to reduce the size of the following `if` statement I have.

```
if [[ "$file_extension" == "MP4" ]] || [[ "$file_extension" == "mp4" ]] || [[ "$file_extension" == "MTS" ]] || [[ "$file_extension" == "mts" ]] [[ "$file_extension" == "AVI" ]] || [[ "$file_extension" == "avi" ]]
then
    echo 'Filesize of '"\"$filename_ext_only\""' before compression was '"$old_file_size"'' >> massCompressResults.txt
    ffmpeg -i "$fileNameWithPath" -c:v libx265 -preset ultrafast -c:a copy "$newfile" < /dev/null
```

Unlike Windows, Ubuntu seems strict about uppercase and lowercase so I was wondering if there was a way using bash to grab the extension regardless of case (i.e. MP4, mp4, Mp4) and still have a program process it (in this case ffmpeg)

My `if` statement works fine (for at least Uppercase and lowercase but not mixed) but its super lengthy was wondering if there was a way to shrink it.

Comment: You may want to have a look to `nocasematch` bash option. See `man --pager='less -p nocasematch' bash`

Comment: `nocasematch` is preferable, but you could also use (for example) `[Mm][Pp]4`

Comment: You could also use `case/esac`

Comment: I ended up using the @() method because it made more sense to me (I didn't know what regex was till I wrote this question.) But your answer did clarify the process for me. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `bash` you could enable an extended option to do this `nocasematch` which is *not* set by default and use the regex operator `~` to combine multiple matches in one.

You could optimize it to

```
shopt -s nocasematch
if [[ "${file_extension}" =~ ^(mp4|mts|avi)$ ]]; then
```

Note that this option is a different when compared to the `nocaseglob` which is used for case insensitive glob expansion (filename expansion). Do *not* use one another interchangeably. See [Additional shell options in `bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html)

One other useful thing to do would be to turn off the option once you are done with it, to not let the option affect your other conditional statements.

```
shopt -u nocasematch
```

---

In response to OP's query on why the regex operator is used over the extended glob flag `@()`, it is just a matter of preference. Both solve the same use case here, its more of a personal choice I would see

1. The extended glob with `==` needs another shell option to be enabled by default as `shopt -s extglob`.
2. The `=~` supports ERE, which supports regex start stop positions using `^` and `$` and alternates match using the `|`. So use this if you are comfortable using the regex match tricks.